# CORS POST request in ZF2 becomes OPTIONS request instead

Tags: php, cors, zend-framework2, laminas

Is there anyway in Zend Framework 2 to allow CORS on my API?

I have already allowed all origins `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Every time I send a `POST` request **with headers** the server responds with 405.

On my access log I see the the request is actually `OPTIONS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to start with your php script should do these checks:

```
// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}
```

Once you do that CORS will be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - extend the `\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController::options` method in your controller, if your controller class is extending from it. By default, it returns a 405, which is probably why you see that response.

Headers can be set via `\Zend\Http\Headers::addHeaders`

Note: "Zend" is currently "Laminas", since Zend Framework has become Laminas.